# How to Get The Dates With Missing Dates in Crystal Report?

Tags: database, oracle11g, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

How to get the dates including missing dates and have them filter by `Employee-No` in crystal report? I am using Oracle database ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB6Ob.png)).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You probably need to read through this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Or else you are getting nowhere with your issue.

Comment: Thanks for guidance. I will keep in my mind from next time